# SSIS OData source to Sharepoint stopped working

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

We have a number of SSIS packages which extract data from Sharepoint lists to a SQL database using a service account.  This stopped working suddenly with the errors

> "Data Flow Task:Error: OData Source failed validation and returned
> error code 0xC020801F."

and

> "Data Flow Task:Error: Cannot acquire a managed connection from the
> run-time connection manager.",

Test connections always fail but get different reasons.

> “ Test connection failed ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Root element is
> missing.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager) “ And
> “
> ===================================**
>
> Test connection failed
>
> ===================================
>
> Root element is missing.
> (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.ODataConnectionManager)
>
> ------------------------------ Program Location:
>
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.ShimSharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri
> uri) at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.UI.ODataConnectionManagerForm.GetWebRequest()
> at
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.OData.UI.ODataConnectionManagerForm.TestConnectionMiddle(Object
> callback) ”

The service account has Full Control permissions and connects to Sharepoint using a browser on my own machine and the server which executes the SSIS package.  My own account which also has Full Control permissions can access the site but cannot connect through SSIS.

We have added the registry keys HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319 /v SchUseStrongCrypto /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /reg:32